# Is it OK to defer an Unlock before a Lock?

Tags: go, mutex, defer-keyword

I'm going over some existing code and see this repeated several times

```
defer mtx.Unlock()
mtx.Lock()
```

This looks wrong to me, I much prefer the idiomatic way of deferring the `Unlock` after performing the `Lock` but the documentation for [`Mutex.Lock`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex.Lock) doesn't specify a situation where the `Lock` will fail. Therefor the behaviour of the *early `defer`* pattern should be identical to the idiomatic way.

My question is: is there a compelling case to say this pattern is inferior? (e.g. the `Lock` may fail and then the deferred `Unlock` will `panic`) and thus the code should be changed or should I leave it as is?

Comment: It _looks_ strange but it _is_ fine. Longe time ago someone claimed that your defering first is faster (not sure if still -- or at all -- true). I think it is inferior because it violates a common linear reading of the code. Lock tan defer is "Lets get the lock and one we have the lock: Don't foget to unlock it". The reversed version is "Don't forget to unlock the lock I'm going to lock next".

Comment: Thanks @Volker, please consider adding this as an answer.

Comment: While @Volker is correct, I think that it's an anti-pattern. The reason is simple: you typically use `defer` to undo an operation which _was already done._ This is plain simple logic, after all. So while deferring unlocking of what is not yet locked is fine techincally, it's not so fine logically, and here we arrive at that principle that “Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute.”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer:

Yes, it's OK. The `defer` call is made after the function returns (well, sort of).

The longer, more nuanced answer:

It's risky, and should be avoided. In your 2 line snippet, it's not going to be a problem, but consider the following code:

```
func (o *Obj) foo() error {
    defer o.mu.Unlock()
    if err := o.CheckSomething(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    o.mu.Lock()
    // do stuff
}
```

In this case, the mutex may not be locked at all, or worse still: it may be locked on another routine, and you end up unlocking it. Meanwhile yet another routine obtains a lock that it really shouldn't have, and you either get data races, or by the time that routine returns, the unlock call will panic.
Debugging this kind of mess is a nightmare you can, and should avoid at all cost.

In addition to the code looking intuitive and being more error prone, depending on what you're trying to achieve, a `defer` does come at a cost. In most cases the cost is fairly marginal, but if you're dealing with something that is absolutely time critical, it's often better to manually add the unlock calls where needed. A good example where I'd not use defer is if you're caching stuff in a `map[string]interface{}`: I'd create a struct with the cached values and an `sync.RWMutext` field for concurrent use. If I use this cache a lot, the defer calls could start adding up. It can look a bit messy, but it's on a case by case basis. Either performance is what you aim for, or shorter, more readable code.

Other things to note about defers:

- if you have multiple defers in a function, the order in which they are invoked is defined (LIFO).
- Defers can alter the return values of the function you end up calling (if you use named returns)

Comment: So there's no chance that the `Lock` will be interrupted by a `panic` somehow? (I'm pretty new to [tag:go] and in other languages a thread may get an exception for multiple reasons).

Comment: @Motti: First off, the actual acquiring of a lock is, by definition, an atomic operation. Secondly in go, routines aren't exactly threads, and panics aren't exceptions. Panics generally cause your application to crash anyway. An uncaught panic would mean the lock is or is not obtained, and if it's obtained it might not be released. But who cares, the runtime is going to terminate everything anyway. I wouldn't worry about that at all